# Multiple providers with implementations system, which design patterns use

Tags: design-patterns

I am trying to determine the best design pattern to use for a full-text search service. The basic logic how i imagine it is coded below, also there's gist: https://gist.github.com/qutwala/1b574a39286a7525c8c7
When i call search() method it should by configuration decide which search engine ( Sphinx, Solr, etc ) and which implementation ( Local, API. ) for that engine to load.

I'm not sure what exactly design pattern to use. At first i look i guess there can be involved *Factory*, *Singleton* design patterns.

With my current implementation i see following problems:

- How to set and when inject all properties class to a certain implementation.
- How to access properties in certain implementation.
- And i guess there could be more these till it's not in prod. :)

As i mentioned before i'm interested in correct way using patterns, so any thoughts comments are welcome.

Code:

```
<?php

Interface SearchEngine
{
    public function getSearchProperties();

    public function setSearchProperties(SearchProperties $properties);

    public function getImplementation($implementation);
}

Interface SearchPropertiesInterface
{
    public function setIndex($index);
}

class SearchProperties implements SearchPropertiesInterface
{
    private $properties = array();

    public function setProperty($property, $value) {
        echo "Set property <br />";
        $this->properties[$property] = $value;
    }

    public function setIndex($index) {
        $this->setProperty('index', $index);
    }
}

class SphinxSearchEngine implements SearchEngine
{
    private $SearchProperties;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->SearchProperties = new SearchProperties();
    }

    private $implementations = array();

    /**
     * @param $implementation
     *
     * @return SphinxSearchImplementation
     */
    public function getImplementation($implementation)
    {
        echo "Returned SphinxSearchEngineAPIImplementation <br />";
        // TODO: on demand load a.ka. singleton?
        $this->implementations[$implementation] = new SphinxSearchEngineAPIImplementation();

        return $this->implementations[$implementation];
    }

    /**
     * TODO: how to inject properties?
     * TODO: what if changed implementation, should be injected in both?
     *
     * @return SearchProperties
     */
    public function getSearchProperties()
    {
        return $this->SearchProperties;
    }

    public function setSearchProperties(SearchProperties $properties)
    {

    }
}

Interface SphinxSearchImplementation
{
    public function search($query, $limit, $offset);
}

class SphinxSearchEngineAPIImplementation implements SphinxSearchImplementation
{
    public function search($query, $limit, $offset) {
        //TODO: how to get properties, index?
        echo "Find results by SphinxSearchEngineAPIImplementation <br />";
    }
}

class ElasticSearchEngine implements SearchEngine
{
    private $implementations = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->SearchProperties = new SearchProperties();
    }

    /**
     * @param $implementation
     *
     * @return SphinxSearchImplementation
     */
    public function getImplementation($implementation)
    {
        return $this->implementations[$implementation];
    }

    public function getSearchProperties()
    {
        return $this->SearchProperties;
    }

    public function setSearchProperties(SearchProperties $properties)
    {
        // TODO: how to inject properties?
        // TODO: what if changed implementation, should be injected in both?
    }
}

class Search
{
    public function __construct() {
        // magic goes here :)
    }

    private $config = array(
        "engine"    =>  "Sphinx|ElasticSearch"
    );

    public function getEngine()
    {
        echo "Loaded engine: Sphinx <br />";
        return new SphinxSearchEngine(); // For example by config loaded sphinx SE?
    }

    public function search($query, $limit, $offset) {
        // TODO: how to decide which engine to use?
        // TODO: engine should have own properties set?

        $this->getEngine()->getSearchProperties()->setIndex('search_index');

        try {
            $this->getEngine()->getImplementation('local|api')->search($query, $limit, $offset);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // TODO: What to do now, fallback to another engine?
        }
    }
}

$search = new Search();
$search->search('my search query', 10, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, Strategy pattern is what you are looking for.
So you will have factory class, where you switch between any flags you might have.
Something like below:

```
class Factory()
{
     public Factory CreateFactory(Enum parameter)
     {
        Factory manager = null;
        switch(parameter)
        {
           case 1:
              manager = new ImplementationOne();
              break;
           case 2:
              manager new ImplementationTwo();
              break;
           else:
              break;
        }         
        return manager;
     }     
}
```

Then, you can have ImplementationOne class and so on as usual.

Reference:
[Strategy Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern)

Thank you,